# Get chose select value from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap chosen select field in the div and trying to get selected value but unable to get.Any thoughts what is wrong here,

```
$('#content_' + id).find('#GroupID > option:selected').text() // blank
$("#content_" + id).children('select[name="GroupID"] option:selected').text() // blank
```

HTML mark-up,

```
<div id='content_M-CSP-HID-1301-00V9' data-taburl='xxx' class='tab-pane'>
lots of html...
<div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="panel-body form-horizontal "
                                  <!-- BEGIN: GroupID-->
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label for="GroupID" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Family</label>
                                </div>
                                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <select data-placeholder="Select group" id="GroupID" name="GroupID" data-disable-search-threshold="10" class="chosen-select">
                                             <option value=""></option><option value="100 - Environment">100 - Environment</option><option value="200 - Equipment">200 - Equipment</option><option value="300 - Products">300 - Products</option><option value="400 - Method">400 - Method</option><option value="500 - Personnel">500 - Personnel</option><option value="600 - Management">600 - Management</option><option value="700 - Environmental Impacts">700 - Environmental Impacts</option>
                                    </select>
                                   </div>
                                   <!-- END: GroupID-->
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: What is "id" ? you need to include enough code to see the issue .. HTML markup and all Jquery code

Comment: have you try .val()

Comment: @J.Titus

html added

Comment: @DaniP, html added

Comment: @chungtinhlakho, yup tried val() no luck

Comment: is your html complete?  what group id are you trying to get the text of?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `panel-body` is ***under*** the `content_...`?  I think your jquery is missing the context.  Your code is still incomplete ('lots of html...' does no good) so we can only make a calculated guess.

Make sure your `panel-body` is inside the `content_...` and you can use `.val()` with your `find()` or `children()`.

**Edit:**
How about `$('#content_' + id).find('#GroupID option:selected').text()`?

Comment: Yes it's inside. It's not possible to paste html of the page its huge. So I pasted which is required. I can get the field id with ,

$("#content_" + id).find('#GroupID').attr('id')

Comment: Hi, the following code is fetching the desired value:  $('#content_' + id).find("#GroupID").val(); -Help

Comment: Please check the Edit